# NoDatabaseError when building database with schema (Rails, Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a live app on Heroku, and I'm attempting to build a database for my staging app using the following command:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load --remote staging
```

The first roadblock I hit is this error:

```
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

        bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production
```

After running this command, I get a second error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "appname" does not exist
```

Not great at dealing with database issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common thing you may have to provision a new database you can check the following link

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-role-role-name

But for locally you can do the following

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser appname
```

or

```
createuser -P -d -e appname
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the solution, using createuser -P -d -e appname.